# react-bootstrap-table2 sortFunc never called

Tags: sorting, customization, react-bootstrap-table

I'm trying to customize the sort algorithm of a column.
I saw in the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-sort.html) that I should use "sortFunc" to do so : 
Unfortunately I can't find the way to enter the function ever.

Here is my code :

```
const columns = [
  {
    align: "center",
    classes: "font_orange",
    dataField: "min",
    formatter: priceFormatter,
    sort: true,
    sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
      let fA = parseFloat(a);
      let fB = parseFloat(b);
      console.log('IN');
      if (order === 'asc') {
        return fB - fA;
      }
      return fA - fB; // desc
    },
    style: { whiteSpace: "normal" },
    text: "Min price"
  },
```

The result is a column sorted as a string (like the default sorting algorithm) and no log 'IN' appearing in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have remote enabled:

> All the changes are go though onTableChange listener, it's only way that table give fully control to you

https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-remote.html

that might be the reason why your hook is not called.